# Can't get this PowerShell script to recursively remove the hidden file attribute from all files

Tags: powershell, attributes

I am trying to make a PowerShell script which traverses all subdirectories and removes the hidden file attribute, but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
$param1 = $args[0]

# Check if the directory exists
if (Test-Path -Path $param1 -PathType Container) {
    # Remove hidden attribute from all files in the directory and its subdirectories
    Get-ChildItem -Path $param1 -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Attributes -band [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Hidden) {
            $_.Attributes = $_.Attributes -band (-bnot [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Hidden)
        }
    }

    # Remove hidden attribute from all directories in the directory and its subdirectories
    Get-ChildItem -Path $param1 -Directory -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Attributes -band [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Hidden) {
            $_.Attributes = $_.Attributes -band (-bnot [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Hidden)
        }
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "Directory $param1 does not exist."
}
```

This is something that is very easy for me to do in `cmd`, so I am surprised how difficult this is proving to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To make [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) **include *hidden* items**, you must pass the
  **`-Force`** switch.

  - Unfortunately, this doesn't just apply to hidden items encountered *during enumeration* or *wildcard matching*, but even when directly targeting a hidden item by its full, literal name, a problem that equally affects [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) - see [GitHub issue #6502](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6502) for a discussion (the only exception is when targeting a hidden *directory* via `Get-ChildItem`, so as to enumerate its *children*).
  - Also, support for targeting hidden items *via wildcards* is missing from *other* cmdlets altogether, as discussed in [GitHub issue #6501](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6501).
- However, in the case at hand you're better off calling the purpose-specific standard [`attrib.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/attrib) utility,<sup>[1]</sup>  which offers a much simpler solution:

  ```bash
  attrib -H /D /S $param1
  ```

---

<sup>[1] As an *external executable*, `attrib.exe` can be called from PowerShell just like from `cmd.exe`. It is only `cmd.exe`'s *internal commands* (which usually have superior PowerShell equivalents) that cannot be called *directly*, but *can* be called via `cmd /c` (e.g., `cmd /c mklink ...`)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I'm surprised that PowerShell has this deficiency that makes such a simple file operation impossible!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @paradroid. PowerShell doesn't make it impossible, however: If you add `-Force` to both of your `Get-ChildItem` calls, it should work (and you can probably get away with a _single_ call that omits both `-Directory` and `-File`).